# AJAX call new data but only reload once setInterval has completed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page what is calling data via an AJAX request. The data contains four sets of data that is displayed on rotation every 10 seconds.  At the moment on the 35th second I call the database for the new data so that when it gets to the 40th second and the last slide is displayed and it return to the first the new data is displayed.

Currently this works however, if the AJAX request takes longer than 5 seconds then the first slide is displayed and as the new data is retrieved the slide will be cut short and the whole thing starts again, conversely if the retrieval takes less than 5 seconds the last slide is cut short.

This is what I have:

```js
var views = ['.call_time', '.call_day_average', '.schools_called', '.schools_quoted'];
var html;
$('.loader').show();
update(); // Call the update function so as to get the initial data set

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() { // Set the type swapping running, change every 10 seconds
    $.each(views, function(key, elem) { // Start by hiding all the type views
      $(elem).hide('slow');
    });
    var temp = views.pop(); // Collect the last type view from the array
    views.unshift(temp); // Add the collected type view to the front of the array
    $(views[0]).show('slow'); // Hide the first type of the array
  }, 10000);
});

// Every 35 seconds call the database for the new data set
setInterval(function() { update(); }, 35000);

function update() {
  html = '';
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url( '
    leaderboard / update ' ); ?>',
    type: 'post'
  }).done(function(data) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(data[0], function(company, data2) {
      // Build an html string from the data to diplay on the page
    });

    $('.leaderboard').html(''); // Empty the div ready for the update
    $('.leaderboard').append(html); // Add the new data set to the div
    $('.loader').hide();
  });
}
```

What I would like to do is to call the new data at say 30 seconds and hold it until the last slide displays for 10 seconds, then start the first slide with the new data seemlessly, this is where I am getting stuck though.

How do I go about holding the data and only displaying it once the last setInterval has completed?

Cheers in advance

Comment: Just FYI you should really look in to using WebSockets or Server Sent Events. It would make the logic simpler, and also get rid of the AJAX polling, which is a really bad idea.

Comment: instead of calling for new data every 35 secs, why not doing it after the last stage of the animation?

Comment: If I wait for the last slide to time out and then call for new data then the slide that is being displayed at the time is cut short when the new data arrives.  This is what I am trying to stop.

Comment: Please show the HTML structure you have.